# Getting Error while returning jax-rs response in http with Spring-Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jax-rs, cxf

I am using spring-boot 2.2 with cxf 3.4.4
Getting Error "No message body writer found for class : class x.y.z.Test"

```
[ERROR] - No message body writer found for class : class x.y.z.Test. (CachingMessageBodyWriter.java:getWriter:89)
[ERROR] - Problem with writing the data, class x.y.z.Test, ContentType: application/json (JAXRSUtils.java:logMessageHandlerProblem:1864)
[WARN] - javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
at
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your code and pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. I was using CXF jaxrs with Spring Boot 2.2.
I was not scanning JsonJacksonProvider in cxf.jaxrs.classes-scan-packages, so just added a complete path.